*.deps.json and *.runtimeconfig.json missing for some projects if multiple projects have output type set to Exe/WinExe
*.deps.json and *.runtimeconfig.json are created for all projects that have output type set to Exe/WinExe, but as soon as the build process starts building the second project, it deletes those files for the first project.
I have just migrated my WPF application from .NET Framework to .NET Core. Is has several projects which have output type set to library, one project set as WinExe (entry point for GUI app)  and one as Exe (entry point for CLI app). When I rebuild the solution, *.deps.json and *.runtimeconfig.json are built for the GUI project, BUT when the build finishes for the CLI project, the files that were created for GUI project get deleted. They DO NOT have the same name so this shouldn't be an issue.
I've searched MS documentation and GitHub and found several suggestions, but none of them are applicable. One suggestion is to put a post-build event that copies those files to a temp location after the first project is built and then copy them back after the second project is built, but I'm afraid this is a hack, not a solution, especially is something changes in the future and build order is switched.
Also, one strange this happens here. Those files are created and deleted when I rebuild the solution, but are not deleted when I clean then build it.
